# How does Swift hash Strings?

Tags: swift, string, hashable

I'm looking through the Swift implementation of String (https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift)

String implements the Hashable protocol, which means that it must provide a hashValue. However, none is provided in the String implementation linked to above. Where can I find this? I'm assuming String inherits it from somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to what mentioned to [Swift String - Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string#relationships), you are absolutely right about:

> String implements the [Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) protocol...

The reason why you cannot see where is the implementation of conforming to `Hashable` protocol in the link for the file that you provided in the question is:

`'String : Hashable'` conformance has been moved to a to a separate file. You can find it here: 
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringHashable.swift; Note that the file is ***StringHashable.swift***, but *not* ***String.swift***.

You can also find the commit of this change here:
https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/4612/commits